# Function of two variables and the chain rule, help

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

$u$ is a function of two variables, $u(x,y)$.

How can I use the chain rule to write
$
u\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}
$ as $\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial u^2}{\partial y}$?

Is it correct to write
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\big(u u\big )= \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\big(u^2\big ) \quad \text{?}
$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct,
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(u u)= \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(u^2).$$
So letting $x=u^2$ we have
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(u^2) = \frac{\partial x}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}= 2u \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}.$$

Comment: Thanks! With $x=u^2$, do you mean $u$ is a function of two variables, $x=u(x,y)^2$?

Comment: $u=u(x,y)$ is a function of $x$ and $y,$ and $x=x(u)$ is a function of $u.$ So $x$ depends of $x$ and $y$ as well. So yes, $x=u^2=u(x,y)^2.$